# Get success confirmation while insert multiple rows using loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

How can I get success confirmation while I am using loop to insert table rows in MySql database table?

My code is like below (I am using `CodeIgniter`):

```
foreach($bookids as $key=>$bookid)
{
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `book` (`invoice_id`,`item_id`,`quantity`,`price`) VALUES (`$invoice_id`,`$product_id`,`$product_quantitys[$key]`,`$product_prices[$key]`)");        
}
```

I would like to get confirmation after all rows inserted successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `affected_rows()` function to check data inserted( or updated) or not.

```
$actual_count = count($bookids); // array of book ids
$inserted_count = 0;

foreach($bookids as $key=>$bookid)
{
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `book` (`invoice_id`,`item_id`,`quantity`,`price`) VALUES (`$invoice_id`,`$product_id`,`$product_quantitys[$key]`,`$product_prices[$key]`)");        
    if($this->db->affected_rows()>0) // data inserted, so it will return 1
    {
      $inserted_count ++;
    }
}

if($actual_count  == $inserted_count )
{
  //throws success message to controller
}
else
{
   // throws error message with mismatch record count
}
```

Comment: kumar_v, Thanks for solution.I would like to implement transaction here. How is it possible??

Comment: refer this tutorial: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$success = true;    

foreach($bookids as $key=>$bookid)
{
    if ($this->db->query("INSERT INTO `book` (`invoice_id`,`item_id`,`quantity`,`price`) VALUES         (`$invoice_id`,`$product_id`,`$product_quantitys[$key]`,`$product_prices[$key]`)"))
    {} else { $success = false}
}

if ($success){
   code on success...
}
```

Explanation: SImply if your query success do nothing, if one of queries will fail flag `$success` will be false and you will know that something went wrong